# Review links should show the posts when they were being reviewed instead of what it looks now

Tags: bug, status-declined, review-queues

People often link to reviews here on Meta.

The links to the reviews show what the posts in their current state, instead of when they were being reviewed.

Isn't this a bit misleading?

I propose that review links show the state of the post when it was reviewed — or that an extra option/link is added for this.

For example:

- [This Triage review link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/22611374) shows the question's current status. When it was being reviewed, it looked [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55182423/3).
- [This Suggested Edit review link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22579326) was for a suggested tag addition, but shows the question's current status. When it was being reviewed, it looked [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55369599/1).

However, not all types of review links are like this.

I'll update this later with some more examples.

Comment: People posting links can point to a revision if they want. I guess they simply choose not to.

Comment: @RobertLongson That's not so easy, since they need to check the time points and choose the right one, and it's possible to make mistake when doing these. Also that will unnecessarily increase the link amounts.

Comment: I seem to have never came across this issue. That or I was totally oblivious (which is likely). Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: @StoryTeller Here is one such example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/22460548 I reviewed at 7:04, the answer was edited at 7:21.

Comment: @WaiHaLee - But the exact action you took is not recorded in the first posts queue. So I don't see the trouble. Worth noting that in suggested edits, the review links to the exact diff.

Comment: Or this (from LQPRQ), where I went with "Looks OK" yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22619841. The post after my edit, two minutes ago, is shown in the review page.

Comment: But yes - some review links do show the posts at the state that the review was started, like suggested edits, close and reopen (I think), possibly others.

Comment: @StoryTeller  One review example:  [triage review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/22611374) here shows the current state, where it [should be this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55182423/3) when it was being reviewed.  And also an [edit review link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22579326) only showing the post's current state, not correctly showing the [state of it was being reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55369599/1) when the editor only added a tag.

Comment: Point taken. You'd make this a better question if you include those examples and explanations in your post instead of in comments. Though I don't think it's a problem in *all* the queues. You should probably prioritize.

Comment: @DavyM  Can it be all of them? Depends on different pov, it can be any one of them.

Comment: Looks like a feature request.  There's no anomalous behavior with the system (e.g. people are linking to reviews and the link works), and this isn't really a discussion about review.  You're asking for a new feature for those who elect to link reviews into Meta posts for future discussion.

Comment: @RobertLongson: That works poorly when the post being reviewed may have since been deleted. /review links allow seeing the deleted post.

Comment: @Makoto I don't see that perspective. I'd always assumed that review links worked the way Tiw wants - i.e. they showed the post exactly as it showed up when it was being reviewed. It's clearly incorrect to show content on the page for a historical review that's got no resemblance to what the reviewer saw. You can't pass any judgement on the correctness of the review from that information, and it's a recipe for confusion and people assuming that reviewers made blatantly wrong decisions when they didn't. Making an *existing* feature actually work properly isn't a feature request, IMO.

Comment: Does anyone know for sure if this has always been the case? I could swear I remember seeing historical versions of posts at historical review links before, and like @StoryTeller I can never remember being caught out by this issue (which *surely* I would've been many times over when following links from Meta, if it's always existed?). Am I mad? Or has this bug in fact been introduced in the last few days or weeks?

Comment: I took a look into this and given the low impact here and the fact that the links still function, we are going to decline this one.